# How to count at specific date range in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created this `mysql` code to count at only specific date range, i dumped the output of my mysql code and here it is:

```
SELECT COUNT(
                IF(
                        DATE(q.date_emailed) BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-28',
                        1,
                        0
                    )
        ) AS 'Feb', 
        COUNT(
                    IF(
                        DATE(q.date_emailed) BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-31',
                        1,
                        0
                    )
         ) AS 'March', 
         COUNT(
                    IF(
                        DATE(q.date_emailed) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31',
                        1,
                        0
                    )
         ) AS 'Jan' 
        FROM
            database.quotes q
        WHERE (DATE(q.date_emailed) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-31')
```

But this outputs same count for each month, in which i confirmed that february and march has zero counts. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the data type of `date_emailed`?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: the datatype is datetime

Answer (score 5):

`COUNT()` counts non-null values.  You can fix your code by using `sum()` instead.  You can also simplify it by removing the `if` statements:

```
SELECT SUM(DATE(q.date_emailed) BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-28') AS Feb, 
       SUM(DATE(q.date_emailed) BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-31') AS March, 
       SUM(DATE(q.date_emailed) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31') AS Jan
FROM database.quotes q
WHERE DATE(q.date_emailed) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-31';
```

In MySQL, a boolean result is treated as `0` for "false" and `1` for "true".  This is a great convenience and allows you to use `sum()` to count the number of matches.

Note that I also removed the single quotes around the column names.  Single quotes should be used for string and date constants, not for identifiers.

EDIT:

You can have this query run faster by using an index on `q.date_emailed`.  However, I don't think the index will be used because of the `date()` function.  You can fix this by changing the logic:

```
SELECT SUM(DATE(q.date_emailed) BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-28') AS Feb, 
       SUM(DATE(q.date_emailed) BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-31') AS March, 
       SUM(DATE(q.date_emailed) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31') AS Jan
FROM database.quotes q
WHERE q.date_emailed >= '2014-01-01' AND
      q.date_emailed < '2014-04-01';
```

Comment: I dont want to add any fields, i just want to count the number of records in the quotes table at that specific date ranges.

Comment: I didn't know what your SUM does but it worked. LOL Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 2):

You should use SUM instead of COUNT if you want to SUM up the 0 and 1.

The COUNT will COUNT the number of row, the SUM will sum up the values.

Comment: They are mysql's if statements, I think 1 is for true and 0 is for false, am i right? why would i want to add them?

Comment: COUNT will count the number of rows, SUM will sum up the 1 and 0. Which is your required output?

Comment: I dont want to add any fields, i just want to count the number of records in the quotes table at that specific date ranges.